# PHP soapClient not working on cronjob

Tags: php, linux, soap, cron

I have a php script, and need to run it everyday. This script has a soapclient, and it works fine if I run it as a script using browser directly. However, it doesn't work if I run it by cron job.

```
$ini = ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");
$client = new SoapClient("https://*****/webservices/webservicesms.asmx?WSDL");
```

And the cronjob I set is

```
13  16  *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/*/domains/****/public_html/CJ-AUTO/cj.php
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Do you care to share what those `Fatal` errors are? Could be very useful in giving us any meaningful feedback.

Comment: @Augwa It's just not working.. there isn't Fatal errors (I've checked the logs)

Comment: How can you be sure that it's running at all?

Comment: @Augwa By "insert" query with log to mysql that the action was done.

Comment: So it is working? So what part of it isn't working then.

Comment: @Augwa the soapclient is api to send sms by outsource system, the SMS doesn't send by cronjob but if I open the url by myself the api will work and the sms will send..

Comment: I think you need to post your code it will probably make itself evident

Comment: @AdirCohen could be that local php executable has no soap libs ? did you try to run from cli without cron ?